# Bounding a function by its arguments

Tags: elementary-functions

Does anyone know any sufficient conditions  (and necessary would be great too if possible) on $f$ such that the following is satisfied:

$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|$, where $C$ is a constant, $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y, \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: This is precisely what it means for $f$ to be "Lipschitz continuous": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Comment: well this is called a Lipschitz function

Comment: ah thanks you two

Comment: In particular, if $f$ is continuously differentiable and has bounded derivative, then it is Lipschitz.

Comment: A useful sufficient condition is that $f$ is differentiable and $|f'(x)| \le C$. This is a corollary of the mean value theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan *continuously* differentiable, no?

Comment: @Clement: no, I don't think so. The mean value theorem doesn't require this hypothesis.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114633/if-f-is-differentiable-on-a-b-then-it-is-also-lipschitz-on-it

Comment: @Clement: my claim is not that if $f$ is differentiable then it is Lipschitz. It is that if $f$ is differentiable *and* its derivative is bounded in absolute value by $C$, then it is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $C$. That, again, is a corollary of the mean value theorem, and it does not require the derivative to be continuous.

Comment: You're right, indeed -- sorry, I took a stupid shortcut there. (if it it continuously differentiable, then it does imply it is bounded, but the important part is only the boundedness).